# How do I remove the WD Quick view icon in menu bar?

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar

I install some app from WD external Hard and it add some incon in my menu bar but I don't know how can I remove it, I try to drag it out of the system bar while holding the "command" key (but it didn't work for this type of icon) I also try to uninstall this app via CleanApp but I can't find it!

sorry because of my low reputation I can't post the image here. :(

Comment: give us a link to the image and I'll be happy to post it for you.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to get an app to stop appearing in the menu bar is to make it stop opening automatically when you log in. Here's how:

I believe that this app is just a login item. Here's how to remove it from your Login Items list.

Open System Preferences (/Applications). Go to Users & Groups -> *your account* -> Login Items. Click the lock at the bottom left and enter your password. Find the Quick View app in the list, select it, and click the minus sign below the list.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

For this particular app, WD provide an uninstaller. It should be in your Applications folder (look for "WD Quick View Uninstaller.app").

You will need to reboot before it is fully removed but it is disabled as soon as you run the installer (I was monitoring its network activity before and after).

It appears to be totally fine to remove it since it only provides information to the user rather than affecting any actual functionality of the drive. If your model of WD drive comes with a management console then all the information is apparently in there (this would be accessed via a browser. For a My Book Live it would be http://mybooklive.local/UI/ ).

Comment: The URL in the answer only works in your own network of course and probably also needs to be changed if your WD hard drive is  not called `mybooklive`.

Comment: Good point, thanks! I've edited to clarify. For some reason when I answered I was thinking that this was a My Book Live specific question!

Answer (score 2):

Apps that want to start at system launch have a couple of ways of doing this. Sometimes, it can be administered from the Login Items screen. But not always.

First check if the app has preference settings of its own. For example, the Brother Control Center has a launch at boot option.

If the WD app doesn't have that option, then you can check for a few places in the /Library -- StartupItems and LaunchAgents (and potentially LaunchDaemons). You'll need to provide an admin's password to delete files from those places. Of course, you should be aware of what you're deleting since things are typically put in those places for a reason.

Comment: According to this WD forum thread, it is just a login item removable from the Users sysprefs pane. http://community.wdc.com/t5/External-Drives-for-Mac/WD-Quick-view-icon/m-p/103248

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is open Activity Monitor and quit the WD QuickView process. Then go to Library/Application Support/WD SmartWare, where you will find WDQuickView.app. Move it to trash and delete it. It's as simple as that.